# Google sheets API v4 - Getting 429 [ Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota) ]

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am encountering an issue when trying to create a spreadsheet via the Google Sheets v4 REST API and getting 429 (Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)) from Google.

It is important to note that all other users are able to use the API without any problems, and the issue occurs right from the first API request for this particular user.

I have already verified from my end that the API requests are not reached the quota limit, and we have not made an excessive number of requests within a short period of time.

API version         : V4
Language Used : Java

API used : https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets

Error response :

```
{
  "code": 429,
  "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)."

}
```

Could you please assist me in finding a solution to resolve this issue? I am unsure about the next steps to take.

Thank you for your help.